# Use jQuery to change wp-caption inline style from img attribute

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying use jQuery to modify the HTML of the WordPress [caption] shortcode, whose HTML is basically like this:

```
<div class="wp-caption" style="width: 310px">
<img class="size-medium" src="..." width="300" height="200" alt="" />
<p class="wp-caption-text">The caption is here.</p>
</div>
```

The problem with this (for me at least) is that WordPress add an extra 10px to the .wp-caption container when an image caption in present. I want to reset this inline style to be the same as the width attribute of the image. I'm not exactly sure how the `var` parts of this should work (or if there's a better way to concatenate a string) and I'd appreciate any help in the right direction:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery(".wp-caption").removeAttr("style");
    var width = jQuery(".wp-caption img").Attr(width);
    var width = jQuery(width).Prepend('width:');
    var width = jQuery(width).Append('px');
    jQuery(".wp-caption").attr('style', jQuery(width));
    });
```

**Update 1:** Now I just need to figure out how to work when there are multiple images on a page. 
I tried wrapping it in a `.each(function(n)` but it still takes the width from the first image and applies it to all the containers.

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery(".wp-caption").each(function(n) {
    var width = jQuery(".wp-caption img").width();
    jQuery(".wp-caption").width(width);
    });
    });
```

**Update 2:** Resolved—see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720310/jquery-each-over-wp-caption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var width = jQuery(".wp-caption img").width();
jQuery(".wp-caption").width(width);
```

Comment: That works, except that when there are multiple images on a page it takes the width from the first image and applies it to all the containers. Any idea how to do each one?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = $(".wp-caption img").attr("width") + "px";
    $(".wp-caption").css('width', width);
});
```

Comment: ...except when there are multiple images on a page it takes the width from the first image and applies it to all the containers. Any idea how to do each one?