# jQuery .each() over .wp-caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, each

WordPress add an extra 10px to the `.wp-caption` container when a caption in present. I'm trying to use jQuery to remove the extra 10px. I've been able to do this thanks to the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628758/use-jquery-to-change-wp-caption-inline-style-from-img-attribute), but I realized that b/c there are sometimes multiple images in a post, I need to use something to the effect of `.each()` to iterate. The code below works for the first image but then wrongly applies the first image's with to the container of the second image. How can I correct the `.each()` to work properly?

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery(".wp-caption").each(function(n) {
    var width = jQuery(".wp-caption img").width();
    jQuery(".wp-caption").width(width);
    });
    });
```

Example w/ [javascript on](http://dev.airve.com/blogx/2011/07/test-wp-caption-js/)

Example w/ [javascript off](http://dev.airve.com/blogx/2011/07/test-wp-caption-no-js/)

**Update:** The most streamlined solution from below:

```
jQuery().ready(function( $ ) {
    $(".wp-caption").width(function() {
        return $('img', this).width();  
    });
});
```

Or substituting `$` with `jQuery` to prevent conflicts:

```
jQuery().ready(function( jQuery ) {
    jQuery(".wp-caption").width(function() {
        return jQuery('img', this).width(); 
    });
});
```

Both work! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a reference to the current element in the `.each()`.

```
jQuery().ready(function( $ ) {
    $(".wp-caption").each(function(n) {
        var width = $(this).find("img").width();
        $(this).width(width);
    });
});
```

...so from `this`, you use the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get the descendant `<img>`, and its `width()`.

You could also pass a function directly to `width()`, and it will iterate for you.

```
jQuery().ready(function( $ ) {
    $(".wp-caption").width(function(i,val) {
        return $(this).find("img").width();
    });
});
```

...here, the return value of the function will be the width set to the current `.wp-caption`.

---

**EDIT:** Updated to use the common `$` reference inside the `.ready()` handler.

Comment: any reason to use `jQuery` over `$`?

Comment: When you get paid by the character? ;o) Actually, I think WordPress calls `.noConflict()` by default. Good point though. I'll update to use the `.ready()` parameter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should just be `jQuery.`, not `jQuery().`

Comment: +1 - The second version is more idiomatic. You can even drop `i` and `val`. And it should be `jQuery(function () { ... })` (no `ready` necessary), plus you can shorten to `jQuery("img", this).width()`

Comment: @Alnitak: That form actually works, though it isn't officially supported. Doing `jQuery.ready()` won't work because `.ready()` is prototyped, instead of a property of the global `jQuery`. You could however do `jQuery.fn.ready()`, and it would work, though again not officially supported.

Comment: and don't forget that `$(this).find("img")` is equivalent to `$('img', this)` and the latter doesn't create an unused jQuery object for `$(this)`.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, the params aren't needed, though I then to include them in answers for educational purposes. And though `$(document).ready()`, is the official way, currently the `document` part is actually ignored.

Comment: @patrick ah, that makes sense about `document` being ignored, so `jQuery().ready()` is just working on an empty jQuery object.  Thx.

Comment: @Alnitak: `$('img', this)` is a little more expensive, and doesn't prevent an extra jQuery object. It just gets flipped around and the `jQuery()` method is recursively called with `jQuery(this).find("img")`. So it's a little more efficient (and clear IMO) to use `.find()`.

Comment: ...[here's the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L170-174)  if you're interested. :o)

Comment: @Tomalak: Oops... you must have updated your comment. :o) Yes, the shortcut is a nice way to go.

Comment: @patrick: The "little more expensive" part is purely academic, here. :) Technically, you're right. Practically, it's entirely irrelevant. IMHO

Comment: @Tomalak @patrick Yea I was using `jQuery` instead of `$` to prevent conflicts (which I've often found necessary using jQuery with WordPress). It worked both ways on that test link. I never knew about the `noConflict()` either ;)

Comment: @Tomalak: My philosophy is that there are a hundred little micro-optimizations that when taken individually could be dismissed as academic, but when together in great enough quantity, can be significant. Although the code clarity offered by a direct `.find()` is a greater motivator for me. I personally see no compelling reason to prefer `$(selector, context)`, but that's just my preference.

Comment: @patrick: So every time you use `.each()` then, or any other callback-based method in a jQuery chain, for that matter, you should be using a basic `for` loop, for performance. But you don't. And with today's processors, it's not worth it, either. `$(selector, context)` vs `$(context).find(selector)` *is* purely academic in front of this. So yes, I can follow the "preference" argument far better than the "performance" one. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: Touché, but there are compelling reasons to do `$('selector').addClass('whatever');`, like clarity and significant reduction. Whereas `$(selector, context)` *obscures* the meaning of the code to no benefit besides saving a couple characters. Can you see someone not understanding what `$('selector').find('selector')` does? No. It is much clearer than `$('selector','selector')`. I was mainly responding to @Alnitak's statement that it saves an unused jQuery object. So that's where the discussion about optimization ultimately came from. I was just explaining that the opposite is true. :)

Comment: ...But yes, it will come down to preference. :o)

Comment: @patrick I think we are pulling on the same rope here. :) It boils down to code clarity and preference. I happen to like `$(selector, context)`, that's all. No real damage done, one way or the other.

Comment: @Tomalak: No! You must agree with me! Please consider my fragile ego! ;o)